# Prevent Macbook Pro to sleep when lid close - Monterey

Tags: display, sleep-wake, hdmi, monterey, settings

I'm in Monterey, not sure why when I close the lid. The MacBook always goes to sleep with it. Look at my current settings.

[image]

Comment: Display Off and Lid Closed are not the same thing.  The Mac will *always* sleep on lid closure unless it is connected to external power and has monitor, mouse, and keyboard.

Comment: I did, my macbook connected to extermal monitors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Amphetamine to keep your Mac in an awake state with the lid closed - see here: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12.

Comment: Ok, I can try look into that .